# Is there a security risk in exposing MySQL table fields name in form fields?

Tags: sql, forms, field, code-injection

Is there a security risk in exposing MySQL table fields name in form fields? so that both the form field and corresponding table field will have the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. Even if you go out of your way to make sure that your field names don't match with your form names, it's still going to be pretty easy for an attacker to guess the association. I mean, there's only so many ways you can name a field that contains an email address.